# Excel Pivot Table on Analysis Services - Element Name Ordering

Tags: excel, service, pivot, olap, analysis

If you connect an Excel pivot table to anlysis services, the Dimension in the field list show all their available attributes (that then can be pulled into the pivot). Our client wants these attribute names to appear in the selection list in a predefined ordering (not alphabetical). How can this be achieved ?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: You cannot.

But what you can do is using display folders: For each attribute, you can define the "AttributeHierarchyDisplayFolder" hierarchy, for user hierarchies, the property is just called "DisplayFolder": You can enter any text for this property. Then, Excel displays the attributes/hierarchies within folders as configured. The folders are sorted alphabetically within the dimension, and the attributes/hierarchies are sorted alphabetically within the folders again. But by defining appropriate folder names, you can influence the display order at least partly.